# How to initialize unordered_map<string, unordered_set<string>> members using initializer list?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map, initializer-list, unordered-set

I have this class

```
class A {
    unordered_map<string, unordered_set<string>> n_;
  public:
    A(unordered_map<string, unordered_set<string>>& n) : n_{n} {}
};
```

And I want to be able to use the constructor with that syntax

```
int main() {
    A a{{"C", {"A", "B"}}};
    return 0;
}
```

But in the way it's written now, I'm getting error

```
error: no matching function for call to `‘A::A(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’ A a{{"C", {"A", "B"}}};`
```

How can it be fixed?

Comment: Maybe you should use a `const` reference, instead

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add one more `{}` for it. And note that temporary can't be bound to lvalue-reference to non-const. (They could be bound to lvalue-references to const or rvalue-references.) e.g.

```
class A {
    unordered_map<string, unordered_set<string>> n_;
  public:
    A(const unordered_map<string, unordered_set<string>>& n) : n_{n} {}
    //^^^^^
};

int main() {
    A a{{{"C", {"A", "B"}}}};
    //          ^^^  ^^^     elements of unordered_set
    //         ^^^^^^^^^^    for the unordered_set
    //   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   elements (std::pair) of unordered_map (only one here)
    //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  for the unordered_map
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ for A

    return 0;
}
```

I guess you might miss the `{}` for the elements (`std::pair`) of the `unordered_map`; in a similar fashion, if you want to make the `unordered_map` containing two elements, you can write it as

```
A b{{{"C", {"A", "B"}}, {"F", {"D", "E"}}}};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0WD3IqNB2R7NUwVg)

Answer (score 4):

> I want to be able to use the constructor with that syntax

You can provide an *[std::initializer_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)* constructor to do the job

```
#include <initializer_list>

class A
{
    using MapType = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unordered_set<std::string>>;
    MapType n_;
public:
    A(std::initializer_list<MapType::value_type> n) : n_{ n } {}
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
};
```

which has the advantage that **list initialization does not require an extra pair of `{}`**. 
For example maps with two entries:

```
A a{
    {"C", {"A", "B"}},
    {"D", {"E", "F"}},
}; // do not require extra braces now!
```

### ([See Live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/I6np9EyrsZaeWw5l))

Answer (score 3):

On top of Jarod's (correct) answer, you are missing one set of curly braces:

```
int main() {
    A a{{{"C", {"A", "B"}}}};
    return 0;
}
```

From the innermost ones:

You need to initialize `std::unordered_set`:

```
{"A", "B"}
```

Use that set in instance of `std::pair`

```
{"C", {"A", "B"}}
```

Use that pair to initialize `std::unordered_map`:

```
{{"C", {"A", "B"}}}
```

Use that map to initialize an object of `A`:

```
A a{{{"C", {"A", "B"}}}};
```

Answer (score 2):

Temporary cannot bind to non-const (lvalue) reference.

You might change constructor to

```
A(const unordered_map<string, unordered_set<string>>& n) : n_{n} {}
```

or

```
A(unordered_map<string, unordered_set<string>>&& n) : n_{std::move(n)} {}
```

or

```
A(unordered_map<string, unordered_set<string>> n) : n_{std::move(n)} {}
```